# Doctrine2 combined/joined Entity property

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've got 2 entities: Type and Asset for which you can see the definition below.

In order to display a list of Assets in my web app I need to generate an Asset name which is a concatenation of `Type->name` and `Asset->id` (eg: cat-158 or dog-15)

I've just added a method `getName()` to the Asset Entity that fetches the Type name and joins it with the Asset id. Is there a way to do this with annotations so that the name is built using a join statement when fetching the Asset? Basically a property on the Asset Entity that is filled with the proper name/id combination when fetching the Asset, without fetching the type when calling `getName()`?

```php
<?php
class Asset
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue("IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Type")
     * @var \Type
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * Constructs a name from the type and id
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getType()->getName() . '-' . $this->getId();
    }

    // SNIP ...
}

class Type
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue("IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    // SNIP ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this ?

Class Asset extends Type{

}

Comment: Seriously? That makes absolutely no sense, both semantically and programming wise. Asset isn't a Type nor should the entities extend eachother.